# Field inside a cavity of a conductor

Tags: electrostatics

Consider a cavity in any randomly shaped Conductor as shown in the figure
[image]

Where Eo is the field due to σo

And, Ei is the field due to σi

My Question is,

Why don't we take any contribution of Ei when calculating field at any point inside the cavity ?

i.e

Why is the Total field at a point inside the cavity is given by only Ec ?

Comment: Welcome here. If you are new, I'd like to advice you - it is important that you pose the questions clearly. You have several different indicies $E_U$, $E_L$ in the picture (maybe wrongly read) and $E_C$ and $E_i$ in the text. Maybe you dont ask about Faraday cage, but about a charge inside a Faraday cage. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're assuming that the electric field inside the cavity, $\vec{E}_c$, is due only to the charge inside the cavity (let's call it $\rho_c$.)    This is false.  The easiest way to see this is by looking at an example where a conducting cavity has an "off-center" charge in it:

[image]
<sub>(diagram cribbed from [this PhysicsForums thread](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/potential-due-to-induced-charges.694174/))</sub>

The electric field $\vec{E}_c$ due to the point charge inside the cavity is just a radial field.  But the electric field must be normal to a conducting surface when we're just outside that surface;  and the field from an off-center charge inside a spherical cavity won't have this property.  So it can't be the case that the electric field inside the cavity is due *only* to the charges inside the cavity.  Instead, the electric field inside the cavity is due to both the point charge in the center *and* the induced charges on the inner surface:
$$\vec{E} = \vec{E}_c + \vec{E}_i$$

Really, one should think of the electric field inside the cavity as including the electric fields due to the outer surface charge and the rest of the Universe as well:
$$
\vec{E} = \vec{E}_c + \vec{E}_i + \vec{E}_o + \vec{E}_u
$$
But because of the properties of conductors, $\vec{E}_o$ and $\vec{E}_u$ cancel out exactly;  so we can get away with only considering $\vec{E}_c$ and $\vec{E}_i$ to calculate the field inside the cavity.

Comment: Is the diagram in your answer accurate? If yes, why the off-centred charge inside doesn't affect the uniform charge distribution on the outer surface of the conducting sphere?

Comment: @M.GuruVishnu:  the negative charge on the inner surface entirely cancels out the field of the point change, such that the net electric field anywhere inside the conductor is zero. And since the inner surface charge exactly cancels out the field of the point charge, there’s no way for it to influence the charges on the outer surface.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So can we say that irrespective of the position of positive point charge inside the shell, the electric field at outside regions is similar to that of a equal positive point charge placed at the centre of the shell?

Comment: @M.GuruVishnu: yes, so long as the exterior surface is spherically symmetric. The interior cavity doesn’t even have to be a concentric sphere;  it can be anywhere inside the conductor and have any shape.